# in R how do you graph frequency distribution using column value for Count

Tags: r, bar-chart, aggregation

I have a dataframe that has indicators as values of a column

```
X     Y Ind 
1  10000  N
2  10000  N
3  10000  G
4  10000  L
```

I want to create a bargraph using ggplot that will give me the Total Count and Total Y based on Indicator Value side by side . 
I am trying to figure out how to implement an aggregation on the dataframe without summarizing it and creating a Count value per categorical value of Ind

Updated: This

Comment: As the Total Count and Total Y are so different in scale, plotting side by side would result in Total Count almost nonexistent.  DId you really meant side by side?

Comment: @akrun, i get what you mean but i would like to have a way to show atleast the count in the same graph that i am showing the total Y ..is there a way to do that or should i just show two graph separately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option would be to get count (`n()`) and `sum` of 'Y' after grouping by 'Ind', `gather` (from `tidyr` to reshape it to 'long' format) and get the barplot with `geom_bar` (from `ggplot2`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Ind) %>% 
  summarise(Count=n(), TotalY = sum(Y)) %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -Ind) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=Ind, y = Val, fill=Var)) +
            geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```